# Can xtabs be used for mean or median instead of sum?

Tags: r

I have data which looks like 
data.frame':    833233 obs. of  22 variables:

```
 $ ProductId                      : num  105422 105422 143863 170645 397474 ...
 $ Brand                          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Supplier                       : Factor w/ 788 levels "[00000] 武商量贩",..: 1 113 265 154 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
 $ Mode.of.operations             : Factor w/ 3 levels "[1] Distribution",..: 1 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Category                       : Factor w/ 27 levels "[01] Fuits and Vegetables",..: 5 5 9 1 22 22 22 22 22 22 ...
 $ Profit.margin                  : num  0 0 237.95 0 1.16 ...
 $ Profit.margin.percentage       : num  0 0 0.1 0 0.17 ...
```

I used xtabs as following

```
xtabs(Profit.margin~Category+Mode.of.operations,wushang)
```

now this gives me sum of profit margin for each category under each mode.of.operations like this

```
                                         Mode.of.operations
Category                           [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
  [01] Fuits and Vegetables                95103.75         0.00         331445.89
  [02] Livestocks                         282948.03     10982.10          91013.51
  [03] Fisheries                           21632.49         0.00         114708.34
  [04] Food category                       14236.32      5289.90         286585.22
  [05] Daily distribution category       1039396.38     53995.36         222966.99
  [06] Grains                             640183.46    150810.26          64068.74
  [07] seasoning spices                   251716.98    175242.57         156037.71
  [08] canned vegetables                   15938.47     51549.80              0.00
  [09] cigarette, wine and tea            810113.98    550314.93          43743.06
  [10] candy cookies                      605020.64     92855.09         626064.09
```

I am also interested in finding mean, median instead of sum. is there any way xtabs can do it? Or there is some other function which can achieve the desired result.

My data has NA/#NA values so I would like other function to give me 0 instead of NA in output because i have to use `rowPerc` later and it simply skip that row in output which has NA in it.

Edit 1
`tapply` function can give me mean and median but its output has NA in it.

```
> with(wushang, tapply(Profit.margin,list(Category,Mode.of.operations), mean))
```

output

```
                                  [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture
[01] Fuits and Vegetables              29.5904636           NA        43.2753480
[02] Livestocks                        47.9248018     9.076116        89.9342984
[03] Fisheries                         33.5908230           NA        45.7552214
[04] Food category                     13.9435064    13.324685        47.7403332
[05] Daily distribution category       27.8942724    58.563297        41.7854179
[06] Grains                            35.7464660    14.332851        27.0446349
[07] seasoning spices                  11.9870937     8.398877        34.4378084
[08] canned vegetables                  5.0566212     8.977673                NA
[09] cigarette, wine and tea           79.4540977    31.158132       146.2978595
[10] candy cookies                     18.8974463     9.113268        61.0555968
```

and after apply `rowPerc` on it , skips whole row

```
> rowPerc(with(wushang, tapply(Profit.margin,list(Category,Mode.of.operations), mean)))


                                 [1] Distribution [2] Reseller [4] Joint venture  Total
[01] Fuits and Vegetables                                                        100.00
[02] Livestocks                             32.62         6.18             61.21 100.00
[03] Fisheries                                                                   100.00
[04] Food category                          18.59        17.76             63.65 100.00
[05] Daily distribution category            21.75        45.67             32.58 100.00
[06] Grains                                 46.35        18.58             35.07 100.00
[07] seasoning spices                       21.86        15.32             62.82 100.00
[08] canned vegetables                                                           100.00
[09] cigarette, wine and tea                30.93        12.13             56.95 100.00
[10] candy cookies                          21.22        10.23             68.55 100.00
```

how can i make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `na.action` argument.

Comment: @zero323 na.action of which function which will be able to calculate mean, median instead of sum?

Comment: None of these. `xtabs` has `na.action` argument which should be _a function which indicates what should happen when the data contain ‘NA’s._

Comment: To help others, you might mention that the rowPerc function comes from the tigerstats package.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one of it is using the `data.table` package. If your original `data.frame` is called `df` you could do something like this. I am not sure what you mean with 'other function to five me 0 instead', to calculate the stats you can use `na.rm = TRUE' as argument to all three functions.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
sum_stats <- 
  dt[ ,list(mn = mean(Profit.margin, na.rm = TRUE),
            med = median(Profit.margin, na.rm = TRUE),
            st_dev = sd(Profit.margin, na.rm = TRUE)),
      by = c('Category', 'Mode.of.operations')]
```

Please provide a reproducible example next time, so we can test the examples we provide.

Comment: This should work, but it provides data in long format. If you want wide format instead, you can use `dcast()` function in  same data.table package: `dcast(dt,Category~Mode.of.operations,value.var='Profit.margin',fun.aggregate=mean,na.rm=TRUE`. Here we provide `na.rm` argument, which is passed to `mean` function to remove any NA's

Comment: Good point, alternatively you use `spread` from the `tidyr` pacakge on the output.